# JNI method Executed automatically

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have a JNI method as following:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_Test_finalize
(JNIEnv *env, jobject self) {
  LOGD("finalize TID:%d", gettid());
  // write out the trailer and clean up
  _finalize(br_ctx);
}
```

The method in java Test class:

```
public native void finalize();
```

I'm sure that there is one place to invoke Test#finalize():

```
private void shutdown() {
    Log.e(TAG, "Shutting down");
    test.finalize();
}
```

the logs:

```
(24917): finalize TID:24926
```

No "Shutting down" !!!

It's soooo strange. **Can anybody explain it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Object has [`finalize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) called when the garbage collector has detected that this instance is no longer reachable. So the `finalize()` may be called due to lose of reachability, not necessary by `shutdown()`.